# Are there any kittens to attack for no apparent reason?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I recently got my [Goobbue Sproutling](http://ffxiv.gamerescape.com/wiki/Goobbue_Sproutling_%28Minion%29) and the description says,  "Has been known to attack kittens for no apparent reason". Now I'm wondering: are there any kittens in FFXIV for my Goobbue to attack? Or is this just flavour text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although there are a few kittens in the game -- the [Cait Sith Doll minion](http://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/playguide/db/item/66241a2923d/), for example, as well as [a significant portion of the playerbase](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Miqo%27te) -- they can all rest easy for now, because the Goobbue Sproutling doesn't appear to have any special behavior around kittens, barring any exceptionally well-hidden easter eggs. While a similar description also appears in the [German flavor text](http://de.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/playguide/db/item/37d12517e46/), the game's other two languages don't make any mention of kittens at all.

If you're curious, the French flavor text roughly reads "be careful not to get your fingers bitten," and the Japanese is something along the lines of "word is that the cost of feeding him is nothing to sneeze at."

Comment: Ahh it is a shame, I figured if they add that you can do /sit next to a bench, and actually sit on the bench. They would add something like this aswell. Thanks :)